# Ruby: Generate random integers that add up to another number

Tags: ruby, random

I'm trying to randomly generate two integers that add up to a previously selected integer.

For instance, if I have a previously selected value of `12`, I need a method that could generate `[6,6]`, or `[11,1]`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14572356/640577)

Just for fun (I'm sure it's not 100% for negatives etc...) :

```
class Fixnum
  def rand_sum(n = 2)
    arr = (n - 1).times.reduce([]) do |a, _|
      curr_max = self - a.reduce(0, :+)
      a << rand(0..curr_max)
    end

    arr << self - arr.reduce(0, :+)
  end
end

 11.rand_sum
 => [6, 5] 
 23.rand_sum 3
 => [10, 6, 7] 
 11.rand_sum 3
 => [6, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I like the general solution for arbitrary `n`. Not sure about amending `Fixnum`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard agreed, I would definitely put this in a module instead but this was just an example.

Answer (score 5):

Get a random number (call it `a`) between 0 and your previously selected value (`sum`). Subtract `a` from `sum` to get `b`. Return `[a, b]`.

Comment: Shhhh... stop giving away secrets!

Comment: "It was a real nice secret organization we had once."

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random integer, then substract it from the given number.

```
def random_add(sum)
  num = rand(sum)

  [num, sum - num]
end

1.upto 100 do |i|
  p random_add(20)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
previously_selected = xx
a = rand(previously_selected)
[a, previously_selected-a]
```

xx being any number.

Example:

```
>> previously_selected = 213
=> 213
>> a = rand(previously_selected)
=> 122
>> [a, previously_selected-a]
=> [122, 91]
```

Thanks!